Array items not getting updated as and when scrolled to the bottom
I'm creating an Infinite Scroll application. I a certain list of array items which I'm populating data with its respective image and title, a limit of 5 items is set, but, when reached to the bottom multiple items are populating also new items aren't getting updated. Here I'm using fakestoreapi. Watch for the code below.
const PAGE_NUMBER = 1;

  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(PAGE_NUMBER);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=5&page=${page}`
    ).then((res) => res.json());

    setState((prevData) => [...prevData, ...res]);
    setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight + e.target.documentElement.scrollTop + 1 >=
      e.target.documentElement.offsetHeight
    ) {
      fetchData();
      setLoading(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

I have written all the necessary code required for Infinite scrolling. The code behaves bit tricky as the scroller reaches bottom multiple items are loaded, also no new items are getting updated, even though the page is updated in the console and data is displayed accordingly but, is not rendered on UI.
What could be the mistake here. Any changes or modification is highly appreciated.
Live code is available here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/infinite-scrolling-app-without-library-ftkrts

https://fakestoreapi.com/docs - in the docs i don't see anything for page

In your fetchData function you used page value from closure from the first render.
You do useEffect that is executed on component init and inside this useEffect on any scroll event there will be onScroll function executed that was created on init and has page = 1 value from that first render.
so since your scroll handler is dependent on page, you should then reinit listener once page value is changed:

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [page]);

In this case any time your page changes you will have new scroll handler that uses up-to-date page value
